# Since when is "People on this site are idiots." not considered rude?

Tags: discussion, rude-or-abusive

I have found this post in the reopen queue:

[How do I fetch a second image in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814159/how-do-i-fetch-a-second-image-in-javascript)

The edit to the post not only did not make it suitable for reopening, but was a straightforward offense, so I have flagged it as "Rude or abusive".

Apparently, someone saw things differently:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Did something change recently, making such statements appropriate for this site?

Comment: Moderator attention was not required. That was an edit that added in abusive language. It was a one-click rollback.

Comment: This isn’t a change in policy, by the way. The rude/abusive flag is only for when the entire post is *irredemably* rude/abusive. It isn’t meant to be used when the problem can be corrected by an edit. No one is arguing that the language is/was appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray, Thank you for the comment! Indeed I could have rolled it back. But what then? Recently I was trying hard to explain to another user, that he/she should read the _how to ask_ section and improve the question, only to be faced with the question: How can I block you? Hugh? Sorry, but everyone should be aware of the rules. And when a warning comes from a moderator to, say - mind your language, it has much more weight.

Comment: New users don't necessarily know the difference between a moderator and a regular seasoned user. I'm not sure, but I expect moderators get their fair share of rude replies. If a user doesn't want to learn the rules, they don't have to. There's a limit to how many low quality post they can author here. Just close vote and move on if you get a snappy reply :)

Comment: @scopchanov If the user engages in an edit-war after the rollback or if that behavior is repetitive by the same user, _then_ flag it for moderator's intervention. Otherwise, there's no need really to waste moderators' time on this.

Comment: @41686d6564, It reminds me of a true story: Once I was driving my motorcycle with my wife and a bus has overtaken me on a turn, effectively pushing me to the very edge of the road and endangering the live of my wife and me. I've called the police and they've asked me: did you collide. No - I have answered. Then it is ok. Call us again when there is a crash.

Comment: Can't we add a feature to detect abusive content before doing any edit/post?

Comment: @sak that is a really hard problem. I would love it, but to keep up with the amount of variation of abusive content you'd need heavy-weight machine learning. And what the machine would learn is its job would be a lot easier if humans just... went away...

Comment: @user4581301 right but I just felt a standardized ML tool can reduce a lot of overhead and discussions so I suggested it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm totally with you. You could filter a lot of garbage without making Skynet. But it's got to be smart enough to pick of conext.

Comment: @CodyGray Seems like yet another case where a flag is declined based on something that's quite counter-intuitive if you're not aware of all the processes and rules around it.

Comment: I commented earlier instead of answering because I knew this was a duplicate, but was on mobile and couldn't properly search for an appropriate one. I've changed the status of your flag to "disputed" (rather than declined), which is probably what the moderator who handled it originally should have done. I also rolled back the abusive language, which is what you would have ideally done. And I've reached out to the user who made the offending edit. As I mentioned above, "rude/abusive" flags aren't really appropriate in cases where the post is otherwise salvageable with an edit, and that one was.

Comment: If you want to bring inappropriate behavior of a user to a moderator's attention (e.g., so that we can reach out to them), then please use a custom moderator flag to do so. Reserve the spam or rude/abusive flags for cases where the *entire post* is spam or abusive and the only reasonable course of action is to nuke the entire thing. This is what these flags do: request deletion of the entire post. That one didn't need to be deleted, it just needed to have an inappropriate edit, added by a user out of frustration, removed.

Comment: @CodyGray, Thank you for this detailed explanation and the actions taken! Now it is much more clear to me what the best action would be in such cases. If you decide to write this as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: They tell me not to answer questions when I think they're duplicates. :-) But seriously, in this case, I think addressing your specific situation is what's important. I don't think my writing an answer here would have much general value. And I don't need the Meta rep.

Comment: And yet - even after all this attention to the moderator's actions & decisions & curation - the poor guy's ***reasonable question*** is still closed.

Comment: In its current form, it is not something that I consider worthy of re-opening. If you have the domain expertise that allows you to make sense of it, please consider editing and improving the clarity of the question, @Y2020-09.